# asp.net: Can i modify a xml file in the App_Data folder without VS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, directory, app-data

i have a (hopefully) simple question:

Can i modify a xml file located in the App_Data folder without Visual Studio?

I want another person who is not allowed to develop my project in Visual Studio to grant the permission to edit a xml file.

The person should use e.g. notepad++ and simply edit and save the file after opening it from windows explorer.

Is this possible?

I've recognized, that the file is read only and I need to know if the feature of the App_Data folder is working well after removing the read only attribute.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I would be very surprised if the answer is no. As long as you don't remove any permissions from a file, the scenario should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you just have to set the file != read only and make sure that that user or a group he belongs to has read & write permissions to the file.

w7
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/

others, for a specific university, but you ought to be able to figure it out.
https://lbis.kenyon.edu/helpline/networksecurityandfilesharing/settingaccesspermissions